# Vapor Mysql not building

Tags: vapor

Getting build error when I run:

`vapor build --mysql`

Not much documentation on how to install any dependencies for this project in their [website][1]. From the stack trace, it seems im missing 'lmysqlclient' which im not sure if im supposed to add to the linker flags or is this something that needs to be added to the vapor config (im pretty new to vapor).

Here is the stack trace:

```
computer:Server user$ swift build -Xswiftc -I/usr/local/mysql/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -Xswiftc -DNOJSON
Linking CLibreSSL
Compile Swift Module 'TurnstileCrypto' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Jay' (21 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SocksCore' (14 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Polymorphic' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'PathIndexable' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'libc' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Core' (28 sources)
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/mysql/lib'
Compile Swift Module 'Node' (22 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Socks' (5 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Fluent' (35 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Essentials' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'TLS' (7 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Console' (34 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Leaf' (34 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'JSON' (8 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Turnstile' (13 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Random' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Cipher' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'MySQL' (10 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'TurnstileWeb' (8 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'BCrypt' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Hash' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'HMAC' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'FluentMySQL' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'URI' (10 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Transport' (8 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'HTTP' (33 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SMTP' (21 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'WebSockets' (14 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Settings' (10 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Cookies' (11 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Cache' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Routing' (9 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'HTTPRouting' (5 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Sessions' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Auth' (14 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'TypeSafeRouting' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Vapor' (86 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'VaporMySQL' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'App' (3 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/App
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/mysql/lib'
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode/10.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/user/test/Server/.build/debug.yaml
```

Comment: Did you forget to add a link to a website?

Comment: Vapor folks mention you can actually prefix vapor command like so:https://github.com/vapor/mysql/issues/63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/mysql/lib'`

You don't appear to have the mysql headers installed at that directory. Did you install mysql? Are you sure that's where they are located?

Comment: The location where hombrew installs mysql is different than linux. I wish vapor allowed us to pass these compiler flags

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Xcode to build this and assuming mysql is installed properly on your machine (I used homebrew) you need to pass in the `-DNOJSON` flag in the Xcode project under project > Build Settings > Other Swift Flags.

After running `vapor xcode` and assuming your mysql package provider is all [set up](https://github.com/vapor/mysql-provider) open up the project and add in the flag.

Clean the project (⌘K) and you should be good to go.

That is what worked for me

[image]